# Print common line from two files - Bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files and I'd like to find common 1st column on each lines and print 1st & 2nd column of file1.txt and 2 column of file2.txt.

```
file1.txt
A10 Unix
A20 Windows
B10 Network
B20 Security

file2.txt
A10 RedHat
A21 Win2008
B11 Cisco
B20 Loadbalancing
```

Result:

```
file.txt
A10 Unix RedHat
B20 Security Loadbalancing
```

I tried code below but doesn't retrive correct result:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$1; next} $1 in a {print a[$1], $0}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: switch `a[$1]` and `$0` and the order of the files at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2} NR>FNR && $1 in a{print $1,a[$1],$2}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Better explained in a multiline version:

```
# Number of record is equal to number of record in file.
# True as long as we are reading file1
NR==FNR {
    # Stored $2 in an assoc array index with $1
    a[$1]=$2
}

# Once we are reading file2 and $1 exists in array a
NR>FNR && $1 in a {
    # print the columns of interest
    print $1, a[$1], $2
}
```

Comment: Hi @hek2mgl, is it possible to do the same operation on files with columns separated by ';' ?
Thanks.

Comment: What you you mean? The input is delimited by `;` or the desired output? or both?

Comment: sorry, the input is delimited by `;`

Comment: Use `awk -F';' ... ` . `-F` allows you to choose the input field delimiter.

Comment: perfect !
sorry, but I have now new inputs: IP address,is it the same way ?
`file1
    NA;10.1.1.1
    abc.con;10.10.10.10`

`file2
    tarata.con;10.11.12.13
    NA;10.1.1.1
    abc.con;11.11.11.11`

Answer (score 2):

this is the standard use case for `join`, for files are in sorted order already.  No need to any additional code.

```
$ join file1 file2

A10 Unix RedHat
B20 Security Loadbalancing
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} $1 in a{print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1
A10 Unix RedHat
B20 Security Loadbalancing
```

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for reply. Your solution works also fine with the little example. 
However, I got only the 2 column of the 2 file and some result are truncated.

Comment: Then your input file is not as you've shown us so edit your question to provide more accurately representative input/output. Also check your file for control-Ms as you'll find in files created in Windows - use `cat -v` to see them and `dos2unix` or similar to remove them.

Comment: Exact, I convert file to Unix format and test again, but I got less result. The command provided by @hek2mgl works better. Thanks for your help.